# How does an Nginx Ingress Controller work on Kubernetes?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

Specifically, why do I end up with two external IP addresses when I follow the [directions](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/nginx-ingress-gke) on Google's website for setting up nginx ingress on GKE?

The two IP addresses are for an Ingress resource and a Service resource of type LoadBalancer:

```
> kubectl get ingress
NAME            HOSTS                            ADDRESS        PORTS     AGE
nginx-ingress   example.com                      1.1.1.1        80, 443   1d
> kubectl get service
NAME                            TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)                      AGE
hello-app                       ClusterIP      10.31.251.77    <none>          8080/TCP                     1d
kubernetes                      ClusterIP      10.31.240.1     <none>          443/TCP                      1d
nginx-ingress-controller        LoadBalancer   10.31.246.62    2.2.2.2         80:32603/TCP,443:31763/TCP   1d
nginx-ingress-default-backend   ClusterIP      10.31.241.48    <none>          80/TCP                       1d
```

Here is how I thought it works:

```
User
 ^
 |
Service resource of type LoadBalancer <-- Ingress annotated as class nginx
 ^
 |
Pod resource with Nginx acting as ingress controller
 ^
 |
Service resource of type ClusterIP
 ^
 |
Pod resource with server serving message at /hello
```

This is basically the diagram on the tutorial page I linked to. So I expect the load balancer to be of L4 type and have an external IP (and not cost any money to use!). And I expect the Ingress (despite its name) *not* to have an external IP, because I mark it with the annotation

```
annotations:
  kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
```

which Google is supposed to recognize as saying I do not want the Ingress resource to use their paid L7 HTTP Load Balancer but my own Nginx controller.

I do notice that my `/hello` page is accessible via the load balancer's IP address, but accessing the ingress' address gives a connection attempt refused error. However it is the Ingress resource which has `host:` and `tls:` settings. So which resource do I associate my TLS certificate with? And why does the Ingress resource specify a domain name when it is the LoadBalancer IP at which my website is accessible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not really understand your question, I believe you are a bit confused regarding the ingress resource.

Let me explain a bit, after you run in the tutorial:

```
helm install --name nginx-ingress stable/nginx-ingress --set rbac.create=true
kubectl apply -f ingress-resource.yaml
```

You will have the following situation:

```
$ kubectl get services
NAME                            TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP         PORT(S)                      AGE
nginx-ingress-controller        LoadBalancer   10.11.245.77   external-ip-ONE     80:32172/TCP,443:31908/TCP   12m

$ kubectl get ingress
NAME               HOSTS     ADDRESS           PORTS     AGE
ingress-resource   *         external-ip-TWO   80        1m
```

Checking the external IP in use you will notice that:

- **external-ip-ONE** - corresponds to the forwarding rule, therefore it is the IP you will see in the Load Balancer page
- **external-ip-TWO** - corresponds to the same IP of the virtual machine where the POD `ingress controller` it is running

Therefore no extra IP is "wasted". Basically you connect to the ingress controller that redirects the traffics according to the specification of the ingress resources to the different backends.

Comment: Thanks! My question was indeed why there is a "wasted" IP. So my diagram is basically correct, but as you point out, the IP just comes from the VM. Also, I found the certificate should be attached to the Ingress resource. Somehow it is magically served on the LoadBalancer's IP instead of the Ingress' own IP. I am still confused why the Ingress has any external IP whatsoever (even the VM's) when it seems to only need a ClusterIP, but you answered my question.